# function argument not matching with function call

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
std::string reverse_words(const std::string& in)
{
    std::stringstream ss(in);
    std::string item, result;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
        the_stack.push(item);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < the_stack.size(); i++)
    {
        result += " " + the_stack.top();
        the_stack.pop();
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, when I try to call it here:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    reverse* s = new reverse();
    std::string in = "fdgdfgbjfd gdf gjhfd";
    std::string reverse_words = s.reverse_words(&in);
    cout << reverse_words;
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error on `std::string reverse_words = s.reverse_words(&in);` (request for member 'reverse_words' in 's', which is of pointer type 'reverse*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)). I am unable to understand where I am going wrong in this.

Comment: As a point of clarification, shouldn't the function call std::string reverse_words(const std::string& in) be std::string reverse::reverse_words(const std::string& in) since in main its being used as a method of the class reverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function

```
std::string reverse_words(const std::string& in)
```

takes a const reference, but you pass an address. Remove the `&` when passing the argument

```
std::string reverse_words = s.reverse_words(&in);
                             ^change to->   ^ remove this
```

Next, `s` is a pointer, so you have to call the member function via the `->` operator, like

```
s->reverse_words(in);
```

Side note: even if internally references are usually implemented as pointers, you should not use pointer syntax when passing an argument by reference. In other words, the `&` address-of operator should never be present when passing by reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried taking the `&` out and I continue to get the same error on that line.

Comment: @DemCodeLines, *maybe you meant to use '->'* Pointers and dots don't mix. The compiler could barely be any more helpful there.

Comment: It made the error go away, but now it threw an error on the `cout` line, saying that `'cout' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: @DemCodeLines I suggest you start small, and understand how C++ works. You are missing `std::cout` since probably you are not `using namespace std;`, or forgot to `#include <iostreams>`

Comment: It seems I had taken out `<iostream>` for some reason when debugging an earlier problem with stacks. Oh well, thanks!